# Считывание строки в python amino

Tags: python, бот

Имеется бот для чата, который считывает данные чата и если человек пишет определенное слово или словосочетание - отвечает на нее заготовленной фразой. Бот почему-то пропускает строки, если в них используется пробел. Пример if content[0] == "Вася Кто Ты". Если написать слитно без пробелов ВасяКтоТы- реагирует. Что не так?

```
def on_message(data):
    global ban
    global tim
    global nom
    chatId = data.message.chatId
    nickname = data.message.author.nickname
    content = data.message.content
    vrem = data.message.createdTime[17:19]
    id = data.message.messageId
    
content = str(content).split(" ")
if content[0] == "ВасяКтоТы":
        sub_client.send_message(message=(f"Звали, {nickname}?"), chatId=chatId, replyTo=id)
```

Comment: Вы разделили строку по пробелам, всё логично же

Comment: а можете поправить мой код?  я просто новичок в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С amino не работал, поэтому не могу точно сказать, нужно ли переводить content в строку, возможно это лишнее, но такая конструкция гарантированно будет работать

```
content = str(content)
if content.lower().startswith("вася кто ты"):
    #...
```

Comment: не хвататет `strip()` чтобы убрать пробелы (если их отправляют в начале)

Comment: и я бы сразу `content` привет к виду для проверки, а не трансформировал в условии

Comment: Это всего лишь рабочий пример, с ним проверка на фразы в любом регистре с пробелами гарантированно работает, прочие улучшения кода остаются на совесть автора вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, и правда работает теперь

Answer (score 1):

```
content = str(content).split(" ")
```

Вы делите строку по пробелам, а потом ищете строку с пробелами. Тут явное противоречие. Исправьте это, и все заработает.

Ну и приведите строки к одному регистру, чтобы бот реагировал и на `ВасяКтоТы` и на `вАсЯкТоТы`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
if content[0].lower() == "вася кто ты"
```

Comment: К сожалению все тот же результат.